# A native exception occurred in .Net EXE

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-ce, windows-ce, sqlcedatareader

I have developed a C#.net windows form application to get and update data from /to a SQL server CE database.While I'm running this app on windows ce 6.0 machine, getting following error:

```
A native exception occurred in ItemDB.exe(my exe name).

Details:
Exception code : 0x80000002
Exception address: 0x40e843b4
Faulting module: sqlceme35.dll
offset: 0x000043b4

at    

NavigateMethod.GetKeyInfo(parm1,parm2,...)

at

SqlCEDataReader.FillMetaData(command)

at

sqlCeCommand.InitializeDataReader()
```

So I searched in net and found this link:

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/cant-find-pinvoke-dll-sqlceme35dll-49162.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/10/26/can-t-find-p-invoke-dll-sqlcemenn-dll.aspx

As suggested, I copied ZIP file(because, I didn't get Cab files) and changed this to .Cab.Then I tried to run Cab,But, its saying "this is not a valid wince setup file".

Hope I explained it clearly.Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is almost always caused by a SQL CE version difference between what you compiled against on the PC and what you have deployed on the device.  Make sure that the SQL CE version number is *identical* in both your project references and what is on the device.  Typically I add the reference not from the ".NET" tab in references, but I specifically brows to the reference so I know *exactly* which file is being used, and then manually deploy SQLCE from the same location to the device.

**EDIT*

The location you should be looking for the files to deploy is here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\wce500\armv4i

And your project reference should point here:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Devices\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll

Comment: I did that, Now its showing "Can't find P/Invoke DLL sqlceme30.dll",How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Checked this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/e8f18881-c642-4989-a8e5-873176b3a0fe/cant-find-pinvoke-dll-sqlceme30dll?forum=sqlce I did not find cab file in this location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SmartDevices\SDK\SQL Server\Mobile\v3.0\wce400\armv4 , Its All ZIP file. How to install this?